# Changes to django-appengine-toolkit for Windows

Tags: django, google-app-engine, python-2.7

I want to use django-appengine-toolkit to provide symlinks needed by Appengine to include dependencies in the production runtime environment as discussed [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-appengine-toolkit/0.1.0). Unfortunately, I ran into an "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'symlink' " problem.  A bit of research took me to [this](https://code.google.com/p/apptrace/issues/detail?id=8) solution for apptrace, which indicated it was due to running the code on Windows.  Adding this change with the arguments for

```
kdll.CreateSymbolicLinkA(srcname, dstname, 0)
```

changed to

```
kdll.CreateSymbolicLinkA(path, dest, 0)
```

at _utils.py at line 62 (as shown [here](https://github.com/masci/django-appengine-toolkit/blob/master/appengine_toolkit/management/commands/_utils.py)) fixed the AttributeError and allowed the code to complete and autogenerate appengine_config.py with the necessary sys.path information.

Unfortunately, the dependencies were not populated under the 'libs' directory and I fear that my Python skills failed me at that point.

Can anyone identify what further code changes are needed to populate the dependencies?

Comment: I added the same fix but got the same results as you the task completes but I get no libraries on the lib folder. I really need this to work!

Answer (score 0):

since I really needed this ASAP, I ended up modifying the _utils.py file on appengine_toolkit:

```
def make_simlinks(dest_dir, paths_list):
"""
TODO docstrings
"""
for path in paths_list:
    dest = os.path.join(dest_dir, os.path.split(path)[-1])
    if os.path.exists(dest):
        if os.path.islink(dest):
            os.remove(dest)
        else:
            sys.stderr.write('A file or dir named {} already exists, skipping...\n'.format(dest))
            continue

    try:
        os.symlink(path, dest)
    except:
        import shutil
        sys.stdout.write('Couldn\'t create symlink copying files instead ...\n')
        shutil.copytree(path, dest)
```

Basically if symlinking fails, I just copy everything. Not the cleanest hack but it works